# referencing UITableView to another tableview on a split view based app

Tags: uitableview, reference, ipad

I'd like to understand what's going on here. Basically I have a NumberOneViewController which owns a table view and is showing up on the details view controller on a split view based app.

When a user selects an entry on the NumberOneViewController tableview row, i assign the table view to RootViewController's tableView member like so:

self.tableView = numberOneViewController.tableView;

So the table view on the detail view controller is now gone - which brings me to my first question, what exactly happened here?

Now, I want number one view controller's table view again to show up on the details view controller, but how?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to reload/refresh the table view after you assign it. Just throwing out something off the top off my head since there are no other answers. Good Luck.